# Как спарсить url фото?

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

Извините за тупой вопрос, но как спарсить url фото или сайта?

Дело в том, что сайт выдаёт случайную картинку после загрузки. И как спарсить либо url сайта после загрузки, либо url картинку на загруженном сайте? (и чтобы оно на python 2.7 работало)

сайт - https://source.unsplash.com/random

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Можно воспользоваться `requests`. Допустим `requests.get(url)`, и проследовать за редиректом, вот вам и url картинки

Comment: @Mattern большое спасибо!